# Magnetic Field dependence of the Hall coefficient in cuprate

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, metals

[image]

[The magnetic $H$-Field dependence of the Hall coefficient in cuprate YBCO are shown in a, b](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v531/n7593/full/nature16983.html?foxtrotcallback=true). Hall coefficient ($R_H$) of YBCO at various fixed temperatures, as indicated, plotted as $R_H$ versus $H/Hvs$, where $Hvs(T)$ is the vortex-solid melting field above which $R_H$ becomes non-zero, for two dopings: p = 0.15 (a) and p = 0.16 (b). Upon cooling, we see that $R_H$ decreases and eventually becomes negative at p = 0.15, while it never drops at p = 0.16.

> In experiments, it seems that reading the Hall coefficient can help to detect the number of charge carrier.
>
> (1) How does the number of charge carrier relates to Hall coefficient, in the non quantum Hall like state? In quantum hall like state, we can measure $\sigma_{xy}$ that exhibits the quantized Hall conductance. Here, does  $\sigma_{xy}$ at different magnetic fields help to count charge density, in Fermi liquid like, in superconducting phase, also in AFM or pseudo gap? What does one  expect to see in each phases?
>
> (2) In cuprate, continuing from (1), how does magnetic Field dependence of the Hall coefficient in cuprate help to diagnosis the charge carrier density?